# Couldn't fill logical volume maps

Tags: lvm, raid

So I have a big problem here. On our server, there is an LVM raid with one volume group called `raid`. It contained two volumes, `secured` and `unsecured` and some unallocated space. Today I tried to remove `unsecured` and recreate it with using all of the remaining free space. I ran the following commands

```
lvremove unsecured raid
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n unsecured raid
```

and it said

```
logical volumes cannot contain more than 65534 extents.
  logical extent (0) already mapped.
  Couldn't fill logical volume maps.
  logical extent (0) already mapped.
  Couldn't fill logical volume maps.
  logical extent (0) already mapped.
  Couldn't fill logical volume maps.
  logical extent (0) already mapped.
  Couldn't fill logical volume maps.
  Volume group for uuid not found: GC3toI0uhKos5KLH0OJ6uMFppc9pSSyl00000000000000000000000000000001
  Failed to activate new LV.
```

After that, I cannot use any lvm command anymore, e.g., `lvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` etc. It always says something like this:

```
# vgdisplay
  logical extent (0) already mapped.
  Couldn't fill logical volume maps.
  logical extent (0) already mapped.
  Couldn't fill logical volume maps.
  Volume group "raid" not found
```

Right now, `secured` is still mounted and I can access the data. I am very worried that data may be lost when I reboot. What is going on here? What did I do wrong and can I somehow fix this?

Comment: have you tried vgcfgrestore to restore your previous configuration? does that error as well?

Comment: I am currently backing up the data just in case. Thank you for the hint, I will try that command later.

Comment: Are you using the ancient lvm version 1?

Comment: What is your kernel version? What distribution? What version of the LVM userland tools? What size are the LVs and the PV(s)?

Comment: Ok, back in the office I gathered some more information. Apparently the installed LVM tools have a newer version, 2, than the one the volumes have been created with, 1. I tried running `vgfcfgrestore -M1 raid` but it didn't help - same errors as before. Then I tried a reboot and right now, the machine is not booting anymore. I guess I will have to visit the server room. Maybe it will be wiser to recreate all the volumes and move the backup data to the new ones.

Comment: The 65534 extent limit was a limit of LVM version 1, which is indeed ancient. Can you upgrade and recreate your Volume Group and Logical Volumes using LVM v2? You'll have a more powerful tool and much fewer limitations with v2. Always backup data **prior** to making changes to your system.